# bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') vs. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and include('file.php') vs. get_template_part()

Tags: sidebar, css, include, bloginfo

In my custom theme I'm using `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.jpg"/>` to load my custom logo.

I'm using a custom sidebar for `front-page.php` and that's why I used `<?php include('sidebar-front.php') ?>` to get it.

But when I'm using the 'theme-check' plugin it's suggesting to change the following:

- `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`
- `include()` to `get_template_part()`

So, I did the following:

- `<img src="<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg"/>`, and
- `<?php get_template_part('sidebar-front.php') ?>`

But both failed here. The logo doesn't load and the sidebar isn't too. I used `<?php get_sidebar('front'); ?>` and it's working fine.

I just want to speculate what the problem with those suggestions? It's WP 3.4.2 here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns a value, it doesn’t print anything. So you have to use:

```
echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

`get_template_part()` is just a wrapper for `locate_template()`. But the latter has one advantage: It returns the path of the file it has found. Try the following:

```
$path = locate_template( 'sidebar-front.php', TRUE );
echo $path;
```